# Enterprise Architect: aggregate relationships from classes to their components

Tags: uml, relationship, enterprise-architect

Is it possible in Enterprise Architect by Sparx Systems, when making a relationship from a class in one (packaging)component to a class in another component, that the relationship affects also the components of source and target classes?

In other words, that when you put the components into a diagram, the same relationship is displayed between them as the one between the classes inside? Of course the goal is having only one relationship, so when you delete the relationship between the two classes the relation between the components disappears too.

Comment: Have you seen my response on Sparx' forum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose ComponentA contains ClassA and ComponentB contains ClassB.
And suppose ClassA depends on ClassB.
In that case you would like EA to show a dependency from ComponentA to ComponentB right?

If this is what you are after then, no out of the box that is not possible.
EA will only display relations between two elements as stated by qwerty.

So if you want to show a dependency between ComponentA and ComponentB then that dependency will actually need to exist.

But, you could write some kind of add-in or script to create these dependencies between the components. Seems simple enough. You just iterate the elements in Component A, iterate their dependencies, and add a dependency to the owning component.

If you do it in a add-in you could even do it on the fly when adding/removing dependencies between classes.